# Adjective to something that can be redone

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What adjective could I use to refer to something that can be redone. i.e: for something that can be removed, it would be 'removable', so what would fit to something that can be redone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Redone* is the past participle of the verb [*redo*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/redo) (meaning "do (something) again or differently"), so I would simply add the suffix *-able* to create the adjective ***redoable***.

This would parallel the formation of the existing adjective [*doable*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doable) (meaning "within one's powers; feasible") from the verb *do*.

[Both definitions from Oxford Dictionaries]